# Adsense redirecting to the ad iframe url in safari

Tags: iframe, safari, google-ads-api, adsense, adsense-api

This issue with Adsense happens on safari browsers only

During page load the website will be redirected to the ad url (the src value in the iframe that was provided by adsense i.e https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub...)

Having an anchor to a location on the page in the url triggers it, when there's no anchor everything works as expected.

I hope someone can help!

Comment: Do you have a page that can reproduce it by any chance? Also can you clarify `Having an anchor to a location on the page in the url triggers it`, I didn't get it. Maybe you can add html of the anchor you are talking about into your question.

Comment: if(location.href.indexOf('#') !=-1){location.href = location.href} in body onload caused the page to redirect to the ad url.

Comment: I tried reproducing it on jsbin, but no luck: https://output.jsbin.com/roqebekiye#hello Opening both in chrome and safari works fine. I see page with ad.